# I can't find the maven plugin org.maven.ide.eclipse:lifecycle-mapping 0.9.9-SNAPSHOT

Tags: maven-2, m2eclipse

I have a maven pom file which depends on this plugin, but I can't find it anywhere online. Is this something which needs to be built from some other piece of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I searched in Sonatype [repository](http://repository.sonatype.org/content/groups/sonatype-public-grid/org/maven/ide/eclipse/) and [svn](http://svn.sonatype.org/m2eclipse/trunk) but I also didn't find jar nor sources. Customizable [build lifecycle mappings](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/M2ECLIPSE/Customizable+build+lifecycle+mapping+for+m2e+extensions+developers) is a experimental feature in m2eclipse. So if you don't need this feature you can comment this plugin.

**Edit**
After some tests I've noticed that if you use Maven 3.0 Embedded runtime your pom will work without complain, but there is still no jar for this plugin in the repository. So there is some kind of magic or I need to read more about Maven3/Embedded :)

[alt text http://img683.imageshack.us/img683/7041/m2eclipse.png](http://img683.imageshack.us/img683/7041/m2eclipse.png)